# How to get screen DPI in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

According to the documentation, I should be able to call ANativeWindow_query to get the XDPI and YDPI.
However the #defines for these two items, ANATIVEWINDOW_QUERY_XDPI and ANATIVEWINDOW_QUERY_YDPI, are not defined anywhere.
You also cannot directly access the xdpi and ydpi member variables.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

These constants *are* defined, e.g.

[`ANATIVEWINDOW_QUERY_XDPI = 0x10002`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/libs/nativewindow/include/vndk/window.h#163)